# From joint density function to marginal density function with pair (X,Y)

Tags: probability

I need some help. Let (X,Y) be continuous distributed with joint density:

1/$\pi$        if $ x^2 + y^2 < 1$

0          otherwise

I learned it the way when I knew the borders (e.g. $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 1$) But do I now need to integrate to the following borders?

$$\int_{x^2-1}^{1-x^2} 1/ \pi dy$$ for the marginal density function of X. And for Y the same but then with $x^2 = y^2$? Can someone please explain me how to compute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the marginal density is wrong. It is $\int_{-{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}} ^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} \frac 1 \pi dy$ and the value is $\frac {2\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} {\pi}$ for $-1 \leq x  \leq1$ . This is the marginal density of $X$. Marginal density of $Y$ is $\frac {2\sqrt{1-y^{2}}} {\pi}$ for $-1 \leq y  \leq1$